# Why do I fail to set the frame size of a UITableView?

Tags: uitableview

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView set in interface builder. 
In my h-file, I have connected the UITableView *myTableView.
(@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;)

In the bottom of my view, I have a toolbar. This toolbar covers the last cell of myTableView.

After reading around a lot, I find that I can set the height this way:

```
CGRect fr= CGRectMake(0, 0, myWidht, myHeight);
[self.myTableView setFrame:fr];
NSLog(@"test %f",self.myTableView.frame.size.height);
```

This logs : test "myHeight", but myTableView is still covered by the toolbar!!!
I have also tried to set the constraints in interface builder, but I still fail.

Is there a way to fix this issue, so the last cell in the tableview is not covered by the toolbar in the bottom of the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the simulator, and adjusting constraints in interfacebulder solved it :-)